# Linearization of nonlinear plant with system identification in Matlab

Tags: matlab, pid-controller, simulink, non-linear, control-theory

I hope this question fits in here and there is someone who can maybe help me.
I am new to control theory and I have a very complex Simulink model which is nonlinear. I want to have a linear approximation of this model to design a controller for this system. I tried to linearize the model with the Model Linearizer of Simulink but this did not lead to any results.
Now my question is, can I approx this model by using the System Identification Toolbox of Matlab by trying to fit the input/output data to a linear model and use this approximation for control design?

Comment: In its current form, your question is too vague.

Comment: Yes. Just bring the model to its operating point, give it inputs of a few variety like step, pulse, sinusoid, chirp etc. Save the input and output signals (subtract the the steady operating values). Load them into system identification tool box. But this method will be less "*accurate*" than linearising the model directly. You may miss some info if your input doesn't have enough "*variety*".